# How to split the tab view at equal space in the Action Bar in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, tabview

I have added two tab view in the action bar which is looking fine in the portrait mode but is not good in Landscape mode and also in tablet devices. now i need to display two tab view that is to be split up with equal space in landscape mode and large devices like being in portrait mode (you can refer from youtube app which has two tabs that equally split up in both portrait and landscape mode). How can i achieve this? please let me know if know somebody.

output of Portrait Mode.

[image]

Comment: don't use tabview, use the new `SlidingTabLayout`, and follow this link for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033292/align-center-slidingtablayout/27210491#27210491

Answer (score 0):

You should try this in onCreate [slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);](https://youtu.be/WSaSNX5QI-E?t=9m4s)
I also linked you to a slidenerd video where he would explain more about it

Answer (score 0):

You can use app:tabMode as FIXED as shown below.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/pager_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/placeHolder"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/collection_tab"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/blueBG"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```