# Proplem with custon sliding tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, android-custom-view

I imported [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html) sample from developer.android.com
In this app are ten tabs (pic. 1. - reference at the bottom of the question), but i want to do only two tabs.

First of all I changed @override method in this class:

```
class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    /**
     * @return the number of pages to display
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
```

So I have 2 tabs (pic. 2), that located on the left side of the screen. Next step - I set gravity for tab in this position in the code:

```
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;

....//....

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);


    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    setFillViewport(true);

   mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);

    ***mTabStrip.setGravity(1);***

    addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Now the app seems like I need, however text in both tabs gravitate to the center of the screen (pic. 3).

**This is my question:** how can I set text in the center of the tab and how set selected indicator at full length of current tab? (pic. 4)
I tried different ways and I really dont understand how to do it.

**Pictures:** [pic 1, 2, 3, 4](http://my-files.ru/pj0g7h)

P.S. My reputation so small, I cant add images or more than two references. :(
P.P.S. Sorry for my "brilliant" English.

Comment: Try deleting this line `mTabStrip.setGravity(1);` and while using the `SlidingTabStrip` add this line:  `slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [27033292](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27210491/1399597)