# Android TabLayout: distribute evenly

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm looking at the Google class that was used in the Google IO called SlidingTabLayout. Inside that class, there is a method called setDistributeEvenly which allows all those tabs to have an even distribution on the screen - every tab has the same size: [Align-Center SlidingTabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033292/align-center-slidingtablayout)

I'm trying to do the same with the official tabLayout class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

But there doesn't seem to be a method available to make all the tabs evenly distributed.

Am I missing something and is there a method within the class which will let me do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I read this tutorial to get my answer: https://web.archive.org/web/20160314043730/http://panavtec.me/playing-with-the-new-support-tablayout/

You are suppose to set the tabLayout gravity:

```
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

And do not set your tabLayout to scrollable (`app:tabMode="scrollable"`) otherwise the gravity fill will not work.

Comment: I needed to prevent line breaks with app:tabMode="scrollable" and evenly distribute the tabs with app:tabGravity="fill"? Any workaround to ensure the two work nicely together.