# TabLayout ViewPager Icon Show at Corners in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have  Implemented the ViewPager with Three Tabs, Each Tab has only icons and it will show left-aligned. My expected output is tabs will equal space in width. Here is my necessary code and screenshot. please guide me to fix the problem, Thanks in advance.

**JustTabActivity.Class**

```
 public class JustTabActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private ViewPager parent_viewpager;
        ViewPagerAdapter pageAdapter;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
            setContentView(R.layout.aaa_sms_layout);
    
            parent_viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.parent_viewpager);
            setupViewPager(parent_viewpager);
    
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(parent_viewpager);
            tabLayout.setFillViewport(true);
            parent_viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
            tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener(parent_viewpager));
            setupTabIcons();
        }
    
    
        private void setupTabIcons() {
            int[] tabIcons = {R.drawable.icon1,R.drawable.icon5,R.drawable.ic_settings };
    
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#018FFD"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    
        }
    
        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
            pageAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            pageAdapter.addFrag(new fragment_home_new());
            pageAdapter.addFrag(new fragment_userprofile());
            pageAdapter.addFrag(new fragment_settings());
            parent_viewpager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        }
    }
   };
  }
 }
```

[image: Screenshot of my output, Please Help to set Tabs Equally]

Comment: Add this tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL); and remove app:tabMode="scrollable" then try? src: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713958/android-tablayout-distribute-evenly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
```

Comment: Thank you Altaf, I have implemented your code, its working fine. let me know i have add more tab means, this code may occur any problem?, plz give up vote if my question is eligible. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

replace `app:tabMode="scrollable"` with `app:tabMode="fixed"` in layout.xml

Comment: Thanks Avani, i have implemented your code, working fine, plz give up vote if my question is eligible. Thanks